# How can I get the logical name of a test object (that exists in the associated shared OR)?

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

Let´s say I pass a `Browser("MyBrowser").Page("MyPage").WebCheckBox("MyBox")` to a function:

```
MyFunction (Browser("MyBrowser").Page("MyPage").WebCheckBox("MyBox"))
```

Later, the function wants to log the *logical name* of the received test object (which in this case, of course, is "MyBox").

**How could it do that?**

The "name" test object property returns the name that is built if you re-add the test object.
**There is no (documented) test object property for the logical name.**
The runtime object properties *can´t possibly* contain the name since it is not a name from the AUT GUI.

So I think the test object does not know its name. Only the repository "knows" under which name the test object is stored there.

So I will have to inspect the repository itself, not the test object.

The `ObjectRepositoryUtil` API allows me (via `GetChildren`, or other methods) to find the test object in the repository´s test object collection, and use the `GetLogicalName` method to get its name. Fine.

But the only way to get that to work is to obtain a reference to a repository by *loading* it. I get the impression this API is designed to manipulate (or analyze) repos from outside of QTP, not from within a test run. 
I do not want to re-load the repository. I want to look up the test object in one of the already-loaded repositories.

The `RepositoriesCollection` API can tell me which are loaded (by their name and path), but it does not provide a means of obtaining a *reference* to the object instance that *represents* one of those repositories.

**So how *can* I obtain a reference to an already-loaded repository, so I can use `GetLogicalName`?**

**Or generally asking: Given a reference to a "normal" test object contained in the current action´s shared repository, how can I find out its logical name programmatically?**

If there is some ultra-wise QTP wizard a la Motti who knows this can not be done, I´d really appreciate an answer from him even if it reads "it cannot be done" if this is true.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want the "TestObjName" property:

```
function GetRepoName(obj)
    GetRepoName = obj.GetTOProperty("TestObjName")
end function
```

Usage:

```
logicalName = GetRepoName(Browser("MyBrowser").Page("MyPage").WebCheckBox("MyBox"))
'logicalName now equals "MyBox"
```

---

Should you feel the need to reconstruct the entire object chain as a string, you can use the following method "GetFullQtpName" (which also requires GetRepoName plus the 2 extra methods below):

```
function GetFullQtpName(obj)
    dim fullQtpName : fullQtpName = MakeQtpName(obj)
    dim objCurrent : set objCurrent = obj

    do while not IsEmpty(objCurrent.GetTOProperty("parent"))
        set objCurrent = objCurrent.GetTOProperty("parent")
        fullQtpName = MakeQtpName(objCurrent) & "." & fullQtpName
    loop

    GetFullQtpName = fullQtpName
end function

function MakeQtpName(obj)
    MakeQtpName = GetClassName(obj) & "(""" & GetRepoName(obj) & """)"
end function

function GetClassName(obj)
    GetClassName = obj.GetTOProperty("class Name")
end function
```

Usage:

```
fullQtpName = GetFullQtpName(Browser("MyBrowser").Page("MyPage").WebCheckBox("MyBox"))
'fullQtpName now equals "Browser("MyBrowser").Page("MyPage").WebCheckBox("MyBox")"
```

Comment: In case you are wondering, "TestObjName" is sort of documented... but not for many objects. Search for it in the UFT help and you'll see it listed against things like WinButton or other Windows and ActiveX controls, but it should work for all objects.

Comment: Could one find out if a test object is stored in the OR or is generated by description? TestObjName returns the default name that the descirption-generated object would get assigned if stored in the OR.

Answer (score 1):

For convenience, I joined all of these separate functions into a single function (GetFullORName), and it works GREAT!  I use it to give better Reporter.Event info in my custom functions...

```
Function GetFullORName (obj)
    Dim fullUFTName : fullUFTName = obj.GetTOProperty("class name") & "(""" & obj.GetTOProperty("TestObjName") & """)"
    Dim objCurrent : Set objCurrent = obj
    Do While Not IsEmpty(objCurrent.GetTOProperty("parent"))
        Set objCurrent = objCurrent.GetTOProperty("parent")
        fullUFTName = objCurrent.GetTOProperty("class name") & "(""" & objCurrent.GetTOProperty("TestObjName") & """)" & "." & fullUFTName
    Loop
    GetFullORName = fullUFTName
End Function


Public Function CheckObjExist (obj)
    If obj.Exist Then
        Reporter.ReportEvent micPass, "CheckObjExist [" & obj.GetTOProperty("TestObjName") & "]", "Object = [ " & GetFullORName(obj) & " ]" & Chr(13) & "Object exists"
        CheckObjExist = True
    Else
        Reporter.ReportEvent micFail, "CheckObjExist [" & obj.GetTOProperty("TestObjName") & "]", "Object = [ " & GetFullORName(obj) & " ]" & Chr(13) & "Object does NOT exist"
        CheckObjExist = False
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I just came up with has a lot of obvious downsides, including its incompleteness, and looks like this:

```
Function GetLogicalName (ByVal TestObject)
    Dim NameWithType: NameWithType=TestObject.ToString
    Dim TypeProp: TypeProp=TestObject.GetTOProperty ("micclass")
    Dim Suffix
    Select Case TypeProp
        Case "Page" 
            Suffix=" web page"
        Case "Browser" 
            Suffix=" browser"
        Case "JavaApplet" 
            Suffix=" applet"
        Case "JavaButton" 
            Suffix=" button"
        Case "WebCheckBox" 
            Suffix=" check box"
        Case "WebEdit" 
            Suffix=" edit box"
        Case "WebElement" 
            Suffix=" object"
        Case "WebFile" 
            Suffix=" edit box"
        Case "WebTable" 
            Suffix=" table"
        Case "JavaObject" 
            Suffix=" object"
        Case else
            MsgBox "Unknown micclass '" & TypeProp & "'"
            ExitTest
    End Select
    GetLogicalName=Left (NameWithType,Len (NameWithType)-Len (Suffix))
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Logical name can be retrieved by a simple line of code instead of so many lines:

In your case:

The function should return logical name of the object from arguement

```
MyFunction (Browser("MyBrowser").Page("MyPage").WebCheckBox("MyBox"))
```

---

```
Function MyFunction(obj)  

MyFunction= obj.ToString()  'This is an inbuilt method of object in QTP

End Function
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Fails for TOs that are not in the object repository...additionally, the accepted answer is a one liner in essence.